# Почему sizeof(int) = 4 а sizeof(int*) = 8?

Tags: c++, c

Написал следующий код

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int Integer = sizeof(int);
    int PtrInteger = sizeof(int*);
    printf("Integer: %d\nPtrInteger: %d\n", Integer, PtrInteger);
    return 0;

}
```

Вывод следующий

```
Integer: 4
PtrInteger: 8
```

Почему так? Почему `PtrInteger` не равен 4?

Comment: У вас же 64 битная система? Указатель это адрес, размер адреса = размеру слова в процессоре (и разрядности ОС). А вот значение int обычно (так повелось издревле) 4 байта или 32 разряда

Comment: Очевидно, что вы компилируете 64-х битный код. Т.е. указатель размером 64 бита. 64/8==8

Comment: Все указатели занимают 8 байт.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в указателе хранится код ячейки памяти, который в зависимости от разрядности системы занимает 32 или 64 бита, т.е. 4 или 8 байт соответственно, о чем вам и говорит `sizeof`. `int` же имеет диапазон в чисел от −2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647, что соответствует 2<sup>32</sup> вариантам чисел, которые можно вписать в него, а значит он должен занимать 32 бита, или же 4 байта.

Comment: С единственным дополнением: `int` же [обычно] занимает 32 бита, или 4 байта, а значит, имеет диапазон представления от ... и до ... Ни размер, ни диапазон `int` в стандарте не указаны, да и плясать надо не от диапазона, а от размера.

Comment: Не совсем от разрядности системы. Я могу запустить х32 приложение на х64 винде, и там будут 4-байтные указатели.